# Efficient way of generating graphs from source nodes

Tags: algorithm, networkx, graph-algorithm

Let's say I have a graph `G`, and around each node I have a few source nodes `xs`. I have to create a new graph `G'` using `xs=[[a, b, c], [d, e], [f]]` nodes such that they won't conflict with grey donuts as shown in the figure below.

Expected output `G'` is `[[a, d, f], [a, e, f], [b, e, f]]`; all others are conflicting a gray donut.

[image]

I currently solved it by taking all permutation and combination of nodes `xs`. This works for smaller numbers of nodes, but as my number of nodes `xs` increases with bigger graph `G`, it soon becomes 100s of thousands of combination to try.

I am looking for an efficient algorithm which will help me speed things up and get me all the non-conflicting graphs with a minimum number of iterations.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: I'm not clear on the problem.  How do you determine which nodes in G` are connected?  How does the original graph `G` affect the problem?  What is the rationale behind the output being those three triples?

Comment: G' follow the same edge/node sequence as that of G. Original graph G something I want to shift using `xs` and make new G'. The rationale behind those triples is that they _do not pass through donuts_.

Comment: Okay; so there is some existing function to tell you whether a given pair of nodes are connected without intersecting a donut.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're stuck, partly because you haven't posted the attempt you see as taking too much time.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fairly obvious minimum set of edges for each stage of your path.  They are both necessary and sufficient for your solution.  For notational convenience, I'll label the original graph X--Y--Z.  Your corresponding G' nodes are

```
X a b c
Y d f
Z f
```

You do this in two steps:

For each edge in G, you must test for validity each possible edge in G`.  This consists of

```
X--Y   [a, b, c] X [d, e]
    a total of 6 edges; 3 qualify: set XY = [a--d, a--e, b--d]
Y--Z   [d, e] X [f]
    a total of 2 edges; 2 qualify: set YZ = [d--f, e--f]
```

Now, you need only generate all combinations of XY x YZ where the `Y` nodes match.  If you sort the lists by the "inner" node, you can do this very quickly as

```
[a--d, b--d] x [d--f]
[a--e] x [e--f]
```

Most current languages have modules to perform combinations for you, so the code will be short enough.

Does that get you going?

Comment: Yes, I'll definitely try it. I'm using Python with networkx, will share the results once done. Thanks.